# The Orville (tv show spoilers within for latest episode) - Quantum Physics General Properties

Tags: quantum-information

**TLDR**

- Season 1, Episode 11 - New Dimensions (SPOILERS AHEAD!)
- Is the explanation of quantum physics accurate in the latest episode?
- Is quantum physics the real world explanation for how the area within the Doctor Who phone booth and Oscar's trash can could be so vast?

So in the latest episode of The Orville the crew uses quantum physics to solve their problem of existing within a two-dimensional plane by creating a quantum bubble around their ship to keep it from being flattened within a 2d space.

I was happy rolling along until the point that they mentioned putting a three-dimensional bubble within the two-dimensional plane. Knowing that as they left the ship (and their quantum bubble) with a shuttle, the shuttle itself would be flattened as well as anything inside. Therefore they created a three dimensional bubble within the shuttle they used outside of the first bubble to keep the area within 3d while the ship was flattened to exist as 2d.

During the episode they explained that such a situation would be similar to how the Doctor Who phone booth, Oscar the Grouch's trash, Harry Potter tent, etc. can exist. This is what made me curious. Given what we know regarding quantum physics is this explanation accurate? Is the solution that the crew used to solve their problem accurate?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without having watched the episode in question. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is and also note that asking about the general correctness of non-mainstream physical theories is off-topic here - it is very unlikely that the portrayal of quantum physics in a non-educational show is accurate *at all*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I tried to keep it short given the spoiler tag. I think that someone that had seen the episode or could relate to the phone booth and trash can analogy would have understood what I was going for. The episode is still recent so I am only worried about ruining someone's day... I have reworded the question and added some details however. And of course the portrayal may be inaccurate... that is why I asked the question. I don't know. I am looking for someone that does.

Comment: It looks hardcore science babbling, but I don't know more from the Orville except that it exists. In such a question, insert what is going on in the show and ask the question on this way.